# Show that Bessels first kind satisfies the equation below

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that $x^{v}J_v(x)$ satisfies the equation
$$xy'' + (1 − 2v)y' + xy = 0, \quad   x > 0$$
and use this result to find a solution for the equation
$$xy'' − 2y' + xy = 0, \quad     x > 0$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $y(x) = x^\nu J_\nu(x)$ then

$$ y' = \nu x^{\nu-1}J_\nu + x^\nu {J_\nu}' $$
$$ y'' = \nu(\nu-1)x^{\nu-2}J_\nu + 2\nu x^{\nu-1}{J_\nu}' + x^\nu {J_\nu}'' $$

Now plug these into your original equation

Comment: Thank you very much and how could this solve the second equation?

Comment: All you have to do is find the right value of $\nu$ that turns the first equation into the second